# how to return something even if inner join doesnt match

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables

Cursos

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| curso | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Trienios

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_trienio | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| curso_id     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| oe_id        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

those tables are connected through a relationship (as seen through curso_id), and i want to make a query where i retrieve the curso records and the number of trienio records related to each one of them

so i've done this query in laravel

```
$curso = Curso::select([
            'cursos.curso',
            \DB::raw('count(trienios.curso_id) as count')
        ])->join('trienios', 'trienios.curso_id', '=', 'cursos.id')
        ->groupBy('trienios.curso_id');
```

which translates to this

```
select `cursos`.`curso`,
       count(trienios.curso_id) as count
from `cursos`
inner join `trienios`
    on `trienios`.`curso_id` = `cursos`.`id`
group by `trienios`.`curso_id`
```

and it gets me the number of cursos with trienios related to them. HOWEVER, it only gives those who have a number of trienios related to them. the other ones who dont have trienios related to them are not queried, and i want to query them. so, how do i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `leftJoin()`, select `cursos.id`, and group by `cursos.id`:

```
$curso = Curso::select([
        'cursos.id',
        DB::raw('count(trienios.curso_id) as count')
    ])->leftJoin('trienios', 'trienios.curso_id', '=', 'cursos.id')
    ->groupBy('cursos.id');
```

This is the query I want to run:

```
SELECT c.id,
       COUNT(t.curso_id) AS count
FROM cursos c
LEFT JOIN trienios t
    ON t.curso_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` should prevent records from `cursos` from being dropped even if they have no matching counterparts in `trienios`.  As for the error you were seeing, you were selecting `cursos.curso`, which is not an aggregate and which does not appear in your `GROUP BY` clause.  When MySQL is in `only_full_group_by` this is not allowed, hence I changed the select clause to `cursos.id`.

Comment: error. 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'repositorio.cursos.curso' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `cursos`.`curso`, count(trienios.curso_id) as count from `cursos` left join `trienios` on `trienios`.`curso_id` = `cursos`.`id` group by `trienios`.`curso_id`) count_row_table)

Comment: How is this possible?  How then could your original query run?

Comment: ive ended up disabling only_full_group_by and applied your solution (i just changed querying the name row instead of the id one) and it works fine. ty for your assistance